# ExpressionEngine RewriteRule RegEx Throws 500 Error

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

When using categories in ExpressionEngine, a [Category URL Indicator](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator) *trigger word* can be set to load a category by its `{category_url_title}`.

I would like to remove the category "trigger word" from the URL.

Here is what I have so far, with the trigger word set to "category":

```
RewriteRule /products/(.+)$ /products/category/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not an expert at writing regular expressions, but I do a little. I'm 99% sure my RegEx is fine, however when trying to use it as a RewriteRule in my `.htaccess` file, I'm getting a 500 error.

I'm sure it's something stupid, but for some reason I'm not seeing my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update:** Adding a `^` to the beginning of the RewriteRule fixed the 500 error.

```
RewriteRule ^/products/(.+)$ /products/category/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding the "^"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not safe. Take:

```
/products/a
```

The regex group matches `a`.

It will be rewritten to:

```
/products/category/a
```

which the regex matches *again* (this time, the group matches `category/a`). Guess what will happen.

You want `/products/` from the beginning of input *if it is not followed by `category/`*, which means you want a negative lookahead. Also, the `QSA` flag is of no use, you don't have a query string to rewrite (QSA stands for Query String Append):

```
RewriteRule ^/products/(?!category/)(.+) /products/category/$1 [L]
```

Another way to use it (and which I personally prefer) is to use a `RewriteCond` prior to the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/(?!category/)
RewriteRule ^/products/(.*) /products/category/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i like it! I didn't realize it would rewrite twice - makes sense tho! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This Apache RewriteRule should do the job for you*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/(?!category/)
RewriteRule ^/products/(.*) /products/category/$1 [L]
```

With this in place, you'll need to hard code your category links manually:

```
{categories backspace="2"}
    <a href="{site_name}/products/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a>,
{/categories}
```

Which would output the new Category URLs you desire:

```
http://example.com/products/toys
```

Otherwise, if using the recommended [path variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/path.html) when building your category links:

```
{categories backspace="2"}
    <a href="{path=products/index}">{category_name}</a>,
{/categories}
```

Would create links with the [Category URL Indicator](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator) in the URI:

```
http://example.com/products/C1
http://example.com/products/category/toys
```

Which — *while perfectly valid* — would create [canonicalization issues](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/) on your site since the different URLs would appear as duplicate content to search engines.

---

**Credit to [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709840/245264) for brilliant mod_write rule.*